# OperLayers: display markers while fetching them

Tags: javascript, gis, openlayers, openstreetmap

I'm fetching via ajax requests a few thousands points to display on an OSM map.

I get 100 points for each call.

I would like them to show up on the map as soon as they are fetched, while now they show up only when all the calls (around 20) are done.

Here is my code:

```
var source = new ol.source.OSM();
var map_layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: source
});
var map_view =  new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([12, 44]),
    zoom: 9
});
var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [map_layer, ],
    target: 'map-canvas',
    view: map_view
});
var target = $(map.getTargetElement());
target.width(window.innerWidth);
target.height(window.innerHeight * 0.9);
map.updateSize();

var container = document.getElementById('popup');
var content = document.getElementById('popup-content');
var closer = document.getElementById('popup-closer');

var overlay = new ol.Overlay({
    element: container,
    autoPan: true,
    autoPanAnimation: {
        duration: 250
    }
});
map.addOverlay(overlay);

closer.onclick = function() {
    overlay.setPosition(undefined);
    closer.blur();
    return false;
};

var markers = new ol.Collection([], {unique: true})
var vectors = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: markers
});
var style = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
    anchor: [0.5, 1],
    src: 'pin.jpg'
    })
});
var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectors,
    style: style,
});

map.addLayer(layer);

var data = [];
var url = 'some_url';
while (url) {
    $.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: url
    }).done(function(data) {
    url = data.next;
    var res = data.results;
    for (var i=0; i<res.length; i++) {
        if (res[i].latitude & res[i].longitude) {
        var point = ol.proj.fromLonLat([res[i].longitude, res[i].latitude]);
        var feature = new ol.Feature({
            geometry: new ol.geom.Point(point),
            latitude: res[i].latitude,
            longitude: res[i].longitude,
        })
        markers.extend([feature, ]);
        }
    }
    map.render();
    });
}
```

Last instruction you can see (`map.render()`) shouldn't do the trick? It isn't.
`map.renderSync()` isn't helping too.

It would be perfect if it could start rendering the map tiles while fetching those points, now even tiles are rendered after fetching is complete.

Comment: You could try using `vectors.addFeature(feature)` instead of `markers.extend([feature, ])`

Comment: map.render will redraw the map at the next animation frame, not synchronous. You are using ajax with `async: false`, which means you are blocking the redraw until all requests are done. Removing `async: false` should work.

Comment: @MoonE simply removing `async: false` just crash the browser, because each call generates another one and it ends making hundreds of them. We need to wait for the response. But you gave a good hint.
I find a way, please have a look on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the good strategy here is recursion. Simply doing async calls isn't enough.

While each call is async (this letting the map start rendering as soon as possible) the next call is done after showing markers from the previous one.

```
var url = 'some_url';
var limit = 100;
var offset = 0;
var total_count = 2000;
fetch_data(offset);

function fetch_data(offset) {
    $.ajax({
    url: encodeURI(url + '?limit=' + limit + '&offset=' + offset)
    }).done(function(data) {
    var res = data.results;
    for (var i=0; i<res.length; i++) {
        if (res[i].latitude & res[i].longitude) {
        var point = ol.proj.fromLonLat([res[i].longitude, res[i].latitude]);
        var feature = new ol.Feature({
            geometry: new ol.geom.Point(point),
            latitude: res[i].latitude,
            longitude: res[i].longitude,
        })
        markers.extend([feature, ]);
        }
    }
    
    offset += limit;
    if (offset < total_count) {
        fetch_data(offset);
    }
    });
}
```